# Mockito.spy VerifyError: Constructor must call super() or this()

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I am trying to execute simple test case, but getting an error. Below is my test case :

```
@Rule
public AemContext context = new AemContext();
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    Resource currentResource = context
        .create()
        .resource("/content/app/en-us/page", "jcr:title", "Title Page", "width", "5","height","9");
    inheritanceValueMap = Mockito.spy(new HierarchyNodeInheritanceValueMap(currentResource));
    Assert.assertThat(inheritanceValueMap.getInherited("width", StringUtils.EMPTY), Is.is("5"));
}
```

Error I am getting is :

> java.lang.VerifyError: (class: com/day/cq/commons/ValueMapWrapper, method:  signature: (Lorg/apache/sling/api/resource/ValueMap;)V) Constructor must call super() or this()

Any solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

This issue usually comes when we use below dependency of uber jar :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.adobe.aem</groupId>
   <artifactId>uber-jar</artifactId>
   <version>6.2.0</version>
   <classifier>obfuscated-apis</classifier>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Try changing the **dependency classifier to apis** , as shown below:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.adobe.aem</groupId>
   <artifactId>uber-jar</artifactId>
   <version>6.2.0</version>
   <classifier>apis</classifier>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: version that we are using is 6.1.0, is that safe if we use 6.2.0 as we are using AEM6.1 version? Also if I apply changes, lots of dependencies stop getting resolve in my file.

Comment: It depends on your requirement to use the aem version. This fix will work for AEM 6.2, I need to check for 6.1